# Непонятное поведение JS в datepicker

Tags: javascript

делаю динамическую таблицу для ввода в базу.

т.е. пользуюсь AJAX. при посылке данных нужно передать ряд параметров (тип, ид записи).

так вот в Input все работает хорошо, а при добавлении datepicker получаю

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>           #53|2015-10-22|53|Руда|33869||timestamp
>
> throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

т.е. код

```
   <input id="53|2015-10-22|53|Руда|33869||timestamp" class="span1" type="text" name="id[53]">

    var $inputs = $('input:not([type="hidden"]),select,textarea');

    $inputs.on('keydown', function (event) {
        if (isEnter(event)) {
            send(this.id, this.value);
            var $next = $inputs.eq($inputs.index(this) + 1);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $next.focus();
            }, 200);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    function send(id, value)
    {
        var arr = id.split('|'); 
    }

    function isEnter(e)
    {
        var res = false;
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
            res = true;
        return res;
    }
```

не работает

Comment: Не хотите воспользоваться `JSON.stringify` для преобразования массива в строку формата json?

Comment: не понятен ход мысли. поясните плиз

Comment: Ага, чего-то не то сказал. Меня смутило название функции `send()`.

Comment: Нужен минимальный, полный код, воспроизводящий ошибку. Ваш код (при добавлении HTML и функции `isEnter` за вас) работает без ошибок в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7r4cq9w/).

Comment: в том то и проблема что код работает с checkbox, dropdown и input без проблем. может проблема в datepicker`e ?

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте в ID не использовать "|", т.е. использовать буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания. DatePicker объект JQuery, хз как он его там строит. Из спецификации HTML5: _Атрибуты ID и NAME должны начинаться с буквы ([A-Za-z]), за которыми могут следовать любое количество букв, цифер, дефисов, подчеркиваний, двоеточий и точек._

Comment: @des1roer вполне может быть. А именно в том, как он преобразует HTML-код и какие обработчики событий навешивает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не JQuery единым жив веб. VanilaJs на ура понял ид элемента

https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker